# Why is vim/tmux recommended over IDEs like VSC and Rubymine for Rails development?

Tags: ide, ruby, ruby-on-rails, vim

(Sorry if this is a stupid question)

I recently asked in a Rails developer slack if it was worth it to make the switch from VSC to Rubymine as I can get free subscription off Github's student developer package.

Most of the replies to my question said I should use vim/tmux instead. I used to use vim to program in C and I thought it was just a simple text editor, not really an IDE.

So, I guess...

- What are the strengths/weaknesses of vim/tmux?
- What are the strengths/weaknesses of VSc?
- What are the strengths/weaknesses of Rubymine?
- Is it simply personal preference to use one over another, or will mastering one really make me more productive than with mastering another?
- What are some reasons to use one over the other?

From what it seems so far from what I've been currently looking at, Rubymine is phenomenal for debugging, vim/tmux is great for editing speed and never having to touch your mouse, and VScode has ease of use/no learning curve.

At the moment, I'm considering just sticking with VScode until I understand what's going on better since a more advanced IDE might obfuscate what's going on. Then in the future, use vim/tmux for editing tasks/general coding, then Rubymine w/ vim keybindings for debugging? I legitimately don't know.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site doesn't feature requests for product comparisions: SR is about suggesting specific software for specific needs you define. For details, see: [Is tool x versus tool y a fair question?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185) So please [edit] your post, list your requirements and ask for software meeting those, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)